# show hidden objects while in edit mode

Tags: modeling

Sorry its a bit of a basic question but I can't seem to fix it.

I have 2 cubes,different objects.

I hide one then go to edit mode on the other, I try the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> or *Mesh > Reveal Hidden* to see the other object while I edit and nothing happens.

I understand this should work but doesn't. How do I show other hidden objects while in *Edit Mode*?

Comment: If you hide object A in Object mode, select object B and go in Edit mode, you can't unhide object A, you need to be back to Object mode to be able to unhide object A

Comment: "*Mesh > Reveal Hidden*" reveals hidden parts of the current mesh, not hidden objects

Comment: You can hide the other object in the Outliner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not supposed to work as you expect. Edit mode is for working with  geometry or data of selected object(s), object mode is for working with the objects in the scene. You can hide and show objects in object mode, and in edit mode you hide or show components of the objects like vertices, edges and faces. Modes are supposed to separate functionality like this for a single object or for multiple objects in the scene.

The operator to show hidden objects actually works from edit mode fine, so no need to wite any scripts actually, you could make a hotkey. In order to do so, you can go to User Preferences(  <kbd>F4</kbd>   ->   <kbd>P</kbd>  ), Keymap tab, then navigate to 3d View Mesh, Mesh(Global) section:

[image]

Then add a new hotkey there for `object.hide_view_clear`
[image]
You can set any key, but I set  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>Shift</kbd>  +  <kbd>H</kbd> , since that is not used and sort of makes sense.  You will be able to show hidden form edit mode then, but for full hiding functionality you need to be able to select objects in object mode.

And by the way, if you are wondering how one finds out about what command to use, I just checked the Info editor after performing the command in the viewport:

[image]

Comment: thanks, I'm realising blender splits the functionality and frankly I don't find it useful, (as I never have the need to hide components) is there any other way to achieve this, maybe via script? another user mentioned using the outliner to unhide the objects while still remaining in edit mode, which works but it can be a problem if there are tons of objects to deal with

Comment: You should switch to object mode to do object operations.  Why do you want to remain in edit mode if you need a bunch of object mode operations? It's possible with a script, but is it really needed? That is unusual. Could you describe the situation in a bit more detail? What are you doing and why do you need this?

Comment: @Jimmy, see the updated answer. Maybe that might be helpful. I am still a bit puzzled about the use case. So I am still interested to hear how you found use for something like this.

Comment: Perfect thanks @Martynas Žiemys, I did have a hotkey to that same command from the object->show/hide->show hidden object menu, and did try to send that command on the script editor but received a "context is incorrect" error. 
adding a shortcut where you have indicated works (I'm not sure why since the command invoked is the same?)

Comment: regarding usecase: often in complex scenes there are objects in front that prevent users from being able to see or easily select the components to edit. its much more convenient to clear the view by hiding all unnecessary objects, do the selection, then restore them back while continuing to edit to see how it affects the scene as a whole. this is the default behaviour in Maya for example which is why I was expecting it to be the same.

Comment: The operator needs the context of the viewport. Who knows why. Maybe some time ago it was supposed to be per viewport functionality. That would make sense. Well... it isn't. If you hide something in one viewport, it gets hidden everywhere making some additional Outliner icons pointless as well. Anyway, this is how operators work in Blender - they take some context and if it's incorrect, you cannot run it. It's [possible to override context for operators though](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html#overriding-context).

Answer (score 3):

You need to be in *Object* mode to unhide an object that you've hidden in *Object* mode. If you are in *Edit* mode you'll only be able to hide and unhide the vertices of the selected object.

That said, while in *Edit* mode, you can hide or unhide other objects in the Outliner.